# How to Connect a Macbook Pro A1501 to an HP Z24i Monitor?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, displayport

I was wondering if there was any software to make my Macbook compatible with my external monitor. I've got a HDMI to DisplayPort adaptor connected to an HMDI cable coming from my mac, but the mac is not detecting the monitor.

The other issue: I am in South America, so other types of connectors would be difficult to come by.

Any thoughts? I really appreciate your help. Here are my specs:

Macbook Pro A1502 with:
2 Thunderbolt ports
1 HDMI port
3 USB 3.0 ports

My monitor is the HP Z24i. It has:
1 USB 2.0 port (lame; won't work with my Mac USB 3.0)
1 DVI Port
1 DisplayPort 1.2 port

Answer (score 1):

I have this same setup, but with an older Macbook Pro (A1278).

Simply get a mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort adapter, and use DisplayPort only. The Thunderbolt port on your Macbook Pro is ALSO a mini-display port and it is compatible with a mini-DisplayPort connector.

Here is an example from monoprice.com http://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=6006

Comment: Noting that the OP says that "...other types of connectors would be difficult to come by." There is no real *software* solution for this, you do need a different adapter.